# Receive JSON response from POST request in Node.js

Tags: node.js, spotify

I'm trying to authorize using Spotify in NodeJS. This is my code:

```js
app.get('/auth', function(req, res){
  if(req.query.error){
    res.redirect('/error');
  };
  var resdata;
  const data = querystring.stringify({
    'grant_type':'authorization_code',
    'code': req.query.code,
    'redirect_uri': 'https://<MYURL>/auth',
    'client_id': process.env.ID,
    'client_secret': process.env.SECRET
  })
  const options = {
    hostname: 'accounts.spotify.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/api/token',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Content-Length': data.length
    }
  }

 const authreq = https.request(options, authres => {

   authres.on('data', d => {
     resdata += d;
   })

   authres.on('end', d => {
     res.send(resdata);
   })
 })
```

When I make the request, I get this response:

```
undefined{\"access_token\":\"<TOKEN>\",\"token_type\":\"Bearer\",\"expires_in\":3600,\"refresh_token\":\"<TOKEN>\",\"scope\":\"playlist-read-private user-modify-playback-state\"}
```

How do I turn this into JSON?

I want to do this in plain NodeJS, without any modules if possible.

Comment: Apply `JSON.parse` on the data.

Comment: @NaorLevi But what about the undefined at the begining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign `resdata` to empty string like this instead of keeping it undefined.

```
var resdata = '';
```

And in your end listener change it to

```
authres.on('end', d => {
     res.send(JSON.parse(resdata));
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `JSON.parse(result.slice(9))`

But there's probably a better way.